# I can't find the error in my code to find the largest prime factor?

Tags: c++, math

I've written a code to find the largest prime factor that has, so far, worked for every single case that i've tested for, yet it fails when I input 600851475143. It keeps giving me 5102831 which is incorrect. I'm not sure why this happens even though I've checked it, help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

long int get_largest_prime_factor(long int);

int main()
{
    std::cout << get_largest_prime_factor(600851475143);
    return 0;
}

long int get_largest_prime_factor(long int prime_Number)
{
    for(long int r = prime_Number - 1; r != 1; r--)
    {
        if(prime_Number % r == 0)
        {
            long int a = get_largest_prime_factor(r);
            long int b = get_largest_prime_factor(prime_Number / r);
            if(a == b)
                return a;
            return a > b? a : b;
        }
    }
    return prime_Number;
}
```

Comment: I get `warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion` on `600851475143`. I think that number is too big for a `long int`. You may need `long long int`.

Comment: 600851475143 is too large to fit in a `long int`. Try `long long int`

Comment: I think you could improve the performance of your program by replacing `long int r = prime_Number - 1;` by `long int r = prime_Number/2;` since a number will never be exactly divided by another number bigger than his half.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your 'failure'.  On my system, your code runs some indeterminately long duration with no output.   Please review [MRE].  FYI - My 64 bit Ubuntu with g++ v9.3.0  system reports :   "sizeof (  long int ): 8" and  "sizeof ( 600851475143 ): 8", and  "INTMAX_MAX is               19 chars (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)", quite a bit  bigger than your 12 digit number.

Comment: Try to replace `600851475143` with `600851475143L` . It will fix the bug, but the complexity of this algorithm is exponential, so it will take years to return a result.

Comment: In my compiler `long long int` and `long int` are of the size, 8 bytes (that's 2^64), so your `600851475143` fits perfectly. Also your program was compiled without any error, but I have been executing it for more than five minutes and it didn't return nothing, so you should change it dramatically or give up of numbers as big as `600851475143`.

Comment: For MRE, you need provide both an nput that fails (your 12 digit), and I think we need to see what the biggest "prime_Number" for which your test passes ... and how long did it take?  I suggest you automate the running of your test with bigger and bigger values ... then have it stop testing when duration exceeds a few minutes.   i.e. measure how fast the duration grows with larger numbers.  Perhaps you can convince yourself that your algorithm needs improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Use this easy algorithm to get the right prime factor:

```
long long int getMaxPrimeFactor(long long int n) {
    int i, max = -1;

    while (n % 2 == 0) {
        max = 2;
        n /= 2;
    }

    for (i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i + 2) 
        while (n % i == 0) {
            max = i;
            n /= i;
        }

    max = (n > 2) ? n : max;   
    return max;
}
```

This should output you:

```
6857
```

Comment: Here's the link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-largest-prime-factor-number/

Comment: Avoid `sqrt` in the loop, it is very slow. Use `i * i <= n` instead, but in that case make sure `i` is `long long`.

Comment: Apparently, it turns out that on modern hardware `sqrt` does not slow the algorithm by much, around 8%. It is not as bad as I thought.